# Wordpress - "parse erro r syntax error unexpected"?

Tags: wordpress, parsing, syntax

I added something to my functions.php and now my site is down. I can't even access the dashboard section.

The problem is I have a caching plugin installed. How do I disable it?

Website is: (removed)

Please help!

Comment: I believe there is an entire stackexchange site devoted to wordpress questions :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that easy if you don't show what you changed in functions.php

The error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /public_html/wp-content/themes/imbalance2/functions.php on line 225` suggests that there's a simple syntax error. Are you sure all opening and closing brackets are correct

Use the following query to disable all of your WordPress plugins:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

Comment: The problem is I have a caching plugin installed. I fixed the syntax error, but I'm not getting the refreshed site. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't disable the plug-in because I'm locked out of the dashboard.

Comment: If you have access to the WP database you can use a query [link](http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/)

Comment: Were there rows updated from the query? What was the output after you ran it?

Comment: 1 row updated. I then tried deleting the caching plug-in manually. Also got me nowhere..

Comment: If you disabled the plug-in from the database, and manually went on the server using FTP and removed the folder from the plugins directory. I would think that the problem is on functions.php. My last guess would be to revert your functions.php file back to its default, then reintegrate your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that after switching to VPS, I was still connecting to old files using FTP. Fixed it, and it was smooth sailing.